# why does `weakly consistent iterator` only reflect modification and removal changes, but does not reflect insertion changes

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have been reading the book `Java generics and collection` and in a section discussing `iterator`, the author mentioned

> Collections which rely on CAS (compare and swap) have weakly consistent iterators, which
>   reflect some but not necessarily all of the changes that have been
>   made to their backing collection since they were created. For example,
>   if elements in the collection have been modified or removed before the
>   iterator reaches them, it definitely will reflect these changes, but
>   no such guarantee is made for insertions. Weakly consistent iterators
>   also do not throw ConcurrentModificationException.

I was wondering, why does `weakly consistent iterator` only reflect modification and removal changes, but does not reflect insertion changes. What is the reason behind defining behaviour like this? What use case does it serve?

Comment: An insertion could be made at the start of the list, at the end of the list, at the current position. This description just said that it does not make any guarantee that the newly inserted value will be visible to the iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's correct. The [official definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly) of *weakly consistent* iteration is:

> - they may proceed concurrently with other operations
> - they will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`
> - they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect
>     any modifications subsequent to construction.

There's no distinction made between removal and insertion.

Comment: thanks shmosel for the clarification, I guess experts also make mistakes once in a while :P

Comment: The other thing to note is that *only* the Oracle sources are definitive.